# JMeter beanshell string comparison issue

Tags: jmeter

I am trying the below code in JMeter BeanShell

I need to compare the value of `OldT` with `${so_tid_1}` which is an exact string and not a variable

```
String OldT = vars.get("OldT"); 
if (OldT.equals("${so_tid_1}")){ 
    vars.put("OldT","ABCD");
}
```

I have observed that the if condition is not executed even when the value of OldT is received as `${so_tid_1}`. But if I change the condition as `if(OldT.equals("some string")` it works fine and I get the expected output.

Any thoughts on why it is not working?

Comment: I just tried this code `String OldT = "${so_tid_1}";
if (OldT.equals("${so_tid_1}")) vars.put("OldT","ABCD");` in JMeter 2.13. The if condition evaluates to true and the `vars.put` is executed. Check your `vars.get` value for white spaces.

Comment: Thanks, This direct assignment of value does work for me too. But the same does not seem to work when value is being fetched from JMeter Variables as `String OldT = vars.get("OldT");` Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: How are you checking that `vars.get("OldT")` is returning `"${so_tid_1}"` ?

Comment: i checked in the log and it is returning only `$(so_tid_1}` and not `"${so_tid_1}"`. I tried to change the condition as `if (OldTCUID.toString().equals("${so_tcuid_1}"))`, but it still does not work

Comment: Log wont print quotes around a string, so that's not it. Again, check for white spaces before or after your string.

Comment: I also tried to explicitly add double quotes to OldTCUID as `OldTCUID = "\""+OldTCUID+"\"";` which gives me the value for OldTCUID as `"${so_tcuid_1}"`. Even then the condition was not executed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82121/discussion-between-maniram-and-rage).

Comment: okie.. i have verified again .. and i do not see any space issues. As i specified earlier, i am getting the expected output when we directly provide the value to OldTCUID. But the same does not work when we provide the values through JMeter variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
 String OldT = vars.get("OldT"); // I need to compare the value of OldT  
                                 // with ${so_tid_1} which is an exact 
                                 // string and not a variable
 if (OldT.equals("\${so_tid_1}")){ 
     vars.put("OldT","ABCD");
 }
```

You need to escape $ sign.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, this did work fine. I tried many a ways, but dint think of escaping $ :)